# Windows 7 Pro OA: getting installation media after removing manufacturer's pre-install?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a download of both Vista (Home Premium) and Windows 7 OEM ISO?](https://superuser.com/questions/505797/where-can-i-find-a-download-of-both-vista-home-premium-and-windows-7-oem-iso)

My Windows 7 Professional became infected after 2 weeks of its usage and I did not copy the image of the harddrive before its use. Now I need to get the harddrive to the manufacturer's state: how can I do it? Where can I get the image of the Windows 7 Pro OA?

*P.s. My computers are by Lenovo.*

Comment: The title in above link mentions Vista, but it is the same question about reinstalling a laptop which came with a OEM install. And it will point you to http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59186.iso

Comment: Your laptop has a restoration image on the hdd I would use that instead.

Comment: If there is no restoration image on the hdd, or if that image has also been corrupted, your vendor should be able to sell you a reinstallation DVD.  Or you may have a friend with Windows 7 installation media, or may be able to buy media (without a license key) cheaply on eBay or similar.  Provided you use the installation key on the sticker on your machine, you shouldn't have any problems activating.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Buying Windows on Ebay is a great way to get homemade copies.  Considering you can get both Windows 8 and Windows 7 witout much hastle directly from Micrsoft ( and/or Digital River their content partner ) I would go that route.

Comment: @Ramhound, personally I'd be more wary of downloading from a link on a community Wiki, even if it says "official download".  (At least with a disk I can check the hologram seal.)  Do you have a Microsoft or Digital River reference as to the legitimacy of those links?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I know for a fact the digital river iso is the exact same iso you would have received if you purchase Windows 7 through Microsoft the day before Windows 8 was released.