# Is there a way to re-install vanilla Windows 8 on an Acer laptop?

Tags: windows-8, acer-aspire, factory-defaults

I want to get rid of the factory settings and default apps on my Acer Aspire v5, and have a clean Windows 8 install on this equipment. Is this possible? Do I have to buy another copy of Windows 8 for this?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a fresh copy of Win8 (the full System Builder version).

Comment: @Karan - To be fair the user only needs the media.  This might be helpful to point out, since otherwise, it might sound like the user has to purchase another license.

Comment: @Ramhound: I will not advocate piracy or illegal downloads here, so do you know of any way as of this date to legally obtain a copy of Win8 SB?

Comment: @Karan Is it illegal to download the ISO but use a legally obtained key?  I think that's what Ramhound was getting at...

Comment: @Kruug: Of course it's not illegal to download the ISO, ***provided*** legal download links exist. If you know of any I'd be grateful for the info as well, so please do share.

Comment: @Karan - I don't advocate piracy either nor suggest they download unverified copies of Windows 8.  If the author has access to the actual media a new license is not required, that was my only point, the author was wondering if a new license is required and its not in this case.  If they have a copy to authorised copy of Windows 8 that media can be used.

Comment: @Ramhound: But that's really the point isn't it? Other than downloading from dodgy/illegal sites or "borrowing" from someone, at present I see no legal way to obtain just the media without paying. If the OP lacks access to someone with a copy of Win8 SB, I don't see how he can do what he wants legally, do you?

Comment: @Karan - I suppose if you word it that way then he has no other options.

Comment: I thought software by itself was irrelevant by now and the permission of using it was the only thing we paid for. But it doesn't matter, might was well use my own means for this one.

Comment: @Karan and overmann, if you torrent the disc image, it's legal, but the license key must be paid for to keep it legal.

Comment: @Kruug: Might be better not to generalise. AFAIK torrenting the ISO is not guaranteed to be legal in all jurisdictions across the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No new licence needed:

See this issue regarding Windows **8** [here](https://superuser.com/a/497663/218300)

Comment: If your answer is wrong it should be deleted. The author is trying to install Windows 8 not Windows 7.  Links to Windows 7 does not help the author in the slighest.