# Windows 10 volume randomly resets to maximum

Tags: audio, windows-10

This has been happening since I installed Windows 10 when it was released.

I have extremely sensitive headphones, so I keep the system volume down to about 10-20 range all the time. 100% is *wayy* too loud. So I'll be on youtube and then I'll pause the video, and after a few seconds if I resume it the volume is EXTREMELY loud, as if the system volume was at 100%. It also happens almost every time I click to a new video.

If I click on the sound icon in the taskbar, it shows it still in the 10-20 range, but if I tweak it up or down it immediately fixes the volume to the actual setting it shows.

My primary browser is Firefox, but I've had it happen in Chrome and it even happens in other applications, such as Windows Explorer (e.g. the little noise it makes when you hit backspace).

I *have* done a search, and am aware of this question: [Windows 10 volume jumps to 100% on random](https://superuser.com/questions/948602/windows-10-volume-jumps-to-100-on-random)

**However, the accepted answer on this question does not solve my problem!** The answer concludes that it is a problem with edge, but it is happening system-wide for me.

I have uninstalled my sound drivers, reinstalled them, and updated them to the latest but the problem still occurs. The second answer on the question above seems closer to home, however I don't have a `Disable all sound effects` checkbox in my playback tab. I've changed every setting in the audio settings but the problem doesn't go away.

I've halfway gotten into the habit of just clicking on the sound icon in my taskbar in preparation for whenever I do anything with audio, but it's extremely frustrating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 10 volume jumps to 100% on random](http://superuser.com/questions/948602/windows-10-volume-jumps-to-100-on-random)

Comment: add a bounty to to original question

Comment: @magicandre1981: Not a dupplicate - question you linked up is about Edge messing things up. This is about driver issue.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

- Click Start and type **Sound** to open the Sound window.
- On the **Playback** tab, select **Speakers/Headphones** and press **Properties**.
- Now go to **Advanced** tab and uncheck **Exclusive Mode** - Allow applications to take exclusive control on this device.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Comment: Unchecking "exclusive mode" agrees with my own research on the problem and more importantly, with my own experience. It is not exclusive to Windows 10 but to instances of the problem with other versions of Windows, and is also not exclusive to any one browser. It is, in fact, a more general fix to the problem.

Comment: This no longer works for me after I updated windows

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work in Windows 10 (10.0.19044 Build 19044) even with the setting set for all audio devices.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have this problem originally, then I updated my drivers.
I grabbed the official Realtek drivers from their website and didn't notice the problem at first, then I have been having the problem ever since.

I removed the drivers, deleted all existence of drivers and let Windows install a driver itself.

Since then, no problems...

Comment: OP says in his question he has already tried deleting/reinstalling his drivers.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP siad in the question "I have uninstalled my sound drivers, reinstalled them, and updated them to the latest but the problem still occurs."

Comment: @DavidPostill : It is not about reinstalling realtek drivers. It is about letting windows install default ones. You need to read peoples' answers with understanding, and stop giving them SE newbie guides.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik Please explain what Realtek has to do with question? OP doesn't mention using Realtek drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Only to remove those privileges to applications didn't work for me, i had to enter also into the **enhancement** menu and set ''**disable all sound effects**'', it should be suggested simply running windows automatic problems resolution tool .

I got that problem since i had to reinstall windows 10 on my ASUS M51AC, i think the problem could rise from the lack of support provided by asus who doesn't provide any sort of driver for his integrated Realtek audio card (at least in my situation).