# second local network makes internet connection slow

Tags: windows, networking, router, home-networking

My home setup is simple: a plain Windows 11 box, connected to the home router via wifi, along with other devices like laptop and tablet. Internet connection is fine.

I try to set up another network using a plain old D-Link router that is **not** connected to internet. If I plug in the network cable into the Win11 box, web access is drastically slower (even if there is no other computer on the other network). Some parts of web pages takes many seconds to load. It feels like Windows is "looking for" internet in the wrong network and takes plenty of time to realize the error, and for every web request. When I unplug this connection, everything returns to normal after some time.

Is it maybe because the ethernet connection has some preference over the wifi connection? If  so, how can I fix this?

Comment: Windows is always looking for Internet so the router not connected may be causing issues. Try changing the network Metric to favor wireless over Ethernet

Comment: Is your case the same as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/970322/8672) ?

Answer (score 0):

Network Interface Metric solved it.

I have set 10 for the wifi connection and 5 for the Ethernet connection and it seems fine now.

Thanks to @John.