# Windows 10 Limited wireless connectivity

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, dhcp

I updated my lenovo E535 to Windows 10.

I have following problem with the wireless connectivity. It seems that even if I connect to the AP the IP address is not assigned using DHCP. Even if I assign manually the IP the connection still not work.
I tried with a different wireless router as well.

I have already

- reinstalled wireless card (Broadcom ) driver
- reset networks with `netsh`
- uninstalled third party firewall
- also tried with another usb wireless adapter  (Netgear 150N)

Is there any other solution to the problem?

Comment: Do other machines on the same wireless network have issues?

Comment: no other machine in the network have the same  problem. I tried also with different wireless networks

Comment: I got the same problem. What type of wireless card do you have?

Answer (score 0):

As the same problem occurs with another usb wireless adapter,
this is not a driver problem, but rather a generic Windows 10 problem.

You can try to repeat the upgrade using a full Windows 10 installation media.
You can get a Windows 10 boot media from Microsoft via the page
[Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Because you will be doing that from a legal
Windows 10 computer, you will not need your Windows product key.

Reinstalling Windows 10 might refresh the Windows component that went bad without destroying anything (but ensure you have good backups just in case).
Download to a USB or a DVD.

If this does not help, ensure that you have your Windows 10 product key,
then use the downloaded boot media to do a fresh install of Windows 10.

If wireless connectivity still does not work, I suggest that you downgrade back
to your previous version of Windows.

In fact, downgrading would probably be the most painless procedure and the one most likely to succeed in solving your problem.
The procedure is described in [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/930439/8672) of mine.
Windows 10 might not yet be up to supporting your computer model.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious compatibility issue with broadcom wifi driver and windows 10. I'm facing this issue ever since I made the OS upgrade. I got one solution, which works based on my luck (It works sometimes, but it fails during the other attempts).

Open device manager (windows+x+m)-> network adapters-> broadcom wifi driver-> right click it and uninstall.

After a while, the windows re-installs the driver, using the inbuilt signatures in the windows 10 (windows 10 might freeze in this process, if it freezes use hard reboot). After re-installing the driver, you might get internet connectivity.

If you still face the issue, comment back.

Edit:- Also try these commands, in the command prompt

ipconfig/release

ipconfig/renew

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo does not provide the wireless driver for windows 10.  The wireless driver for Windows 8.1 would work perfectly fine.  Try installing following driver:

```
Broadcom Wireless LAN Driver (802.11a/b/g/n, b/g/n) for Windows 8.1 (64-bit) - Notebook
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Lenovo does not provide the wireless driver for windows 10. Wireless driver for windows 8.1 would work perfectly fine.