# Windows 10 Visual FoxPro ODBC Issue

Tags: windows-10, odbc, visual-foxpro

I just upgraded from windows 7 64 to Windows 10 64. Now I am having problems with the Visual FoxPro driver. I am using the 32-bit ODBC manager (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe). When I try to add or edit a Visual fox pro source I get the following error:

[image]

I checked for **C:\Windows\system32\vfpodbc.dll** and it does exist.  Why am I getting this error and how do I correct it?

Comment: The driver your trying to use has not supported 64-bit operating systems for awhile now

Comment: It was working just fine in Windows 7 Pro 64 bit before I upgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: Can you try copying the DLL to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`?

Comment: Follow the steps on http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/procmonanalyzer/ to see if it could be anything else that is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check :

- Verify the registry at
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI`, subkey of your
  driver, if the listed files do exist.
  For a 32-bit program the folder `C:\Windows\System32`
  is inaccessible and is automatically substituted to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.
  So a path to System32 should be replaced with SysWOW64.
- You should have installed the [FoxPro 9.0 Service Pack 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304170918/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13959)
  and the [Hotfixes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217131446/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsdata/archive/2009/04/09/hotfixes-for-visual-foxpro-9-0-sp2-are-now-available-for-download-on-codegallery.aspx) (actually only the third one in the list)
- You may need to download and install the [MSXML 4.0 Core package](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506032153/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19662#filelist)

The problem could also be an incompatibility with Internet Explorer 11 or Spartan.
Have you been using IE11 when you were still on Windows 7?

If no solution is found, there is always the option of [downgrading back to Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/926068/how-can-i-downgrade-from-windows-10-to-windows-8/930439#930439).

Answer (score 0):

In case everything else fails, like it just happened to me today, try installing **VFP 9 Service Pack 2 Runtime**, available at http://www.foxpert.com/download/runtime.html and https://github.com/VFPX/VFPRuntimeInstallers

The reasoning is that this installer includes both **VFPOLEB** and **VFPODBC** drivers, and it successfully installed on a Windows 7 machine where all the other standalone installers failed.

Make sure you mark **ODBC and OLE DB** option on **Runtime Files** setup section.

[image]

Older VFPODBC.MSI is available at http://web.sisgarbe.pt/sispub/download/obter.php?produto=VFPODBC