# Installing Windows on laptop with pre-shipped windows: License?

Tags: windows-8, legal

I'm long-term Linux user. Now I have to install Windows 8 on my laptop which never ever ran Windows before. (Well it came with windows preinstalled but I didn't use it at all).

I don't have any kind of license key or anything, I suppose I either removed the sticker with it either it didn't come with sticker in first place. Laptop is Asus N750jv, and it came shipped with 8.1Pro I think, not sure tho.

What do I do to be able to legally install the Windows?

Comment: If you had bought your laptop locally in your place, get in touch with the shop to find out if they provide you with the OEM Windows key. If they can, you just upgrade to 10 after you download and install Windows 10 separately

Comment: I can not do this due to the fact that I've bought laptop 2 years ago in another country, than I'm now at.

Comment: You could contact the manufacturer and purchase the original recovery disks - at a price. You'll need the serial number at least. They'll know what it originally shipped with. Ps: you should always, always create the recovery disks for any new computer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 OEM licences are built into the UEFI firmware, so there's no key sticker in many cases (If there is, they hide it, check under the battery). Just do a clean install of windows 8 from media of the appropriate version ([see the answer that was selected as correct here](https://superuser.com/questions/497660/will-a-clean-install-of-windows-8-recognize-an-oem-license-product-key?rq=1)).

Then you can upgrade that, as per normal to windows 10.

This would be a lot more painless, and you'd know exactly what to do if you'd had a recovery disk made (which is what I typically do with systems with windows preinstalled, even if I intend to run something else on it.)