# Will Windows 8 OEM be accepted by Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, upgrade

I have an Dell Inspiron that came with Windows 8 preinstalled and I have my Windows 8 OEM key stored in the BIOS not on the hard drive. I upgraded to Windows 10 from 8.1 recently but I want to do a clean install (use a windows 10 original ISO and completely wipe my hard drive). When I tried this a year ago with Windows 8.1, it didn't recognize my Windows 8 OEM key and I had to install Windows 8 then upgrade to 8.1, then again upgrade to Windows 10 recently.

Will the Windows 10 installation program recognize my Windows 8 OEM key? Or will I be forced to install, upgrade, upgrade again and clean?

Comment: You can only use a Windows 10 license key to install Windows 10.  The installer will not accept anything else.  You should first upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 8 from within Windows, then from then on, you can install Windows 10 without a license key and the installation will automatically activate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will a clean install of Windows 8 recognize an OEM license/product key?](http://superuser.com/questions/497660/will-a-clean-install-of-windows-8-recognize-an-oem-license-product-key)

Comment: i already upgraded to Windows 10 but the install asks me for the product key so i need to install W8 then W8.1 then W10 which in my opinion is the most retarded thing microsoft ever thought of.

Comment: You can skip entering a product key provided you did the upgrade to Windows 10 at least once on the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start from when your PC has factory installed OEM Windows 8.

**For Windows 8.1 :**

- If you have upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1, its fine.
- If you want a clean install, use "Windows 8.1 Update 1" OEM installation media of SIMILAR EDITION as of your original Windows 8, it should accept your Windows 8 key retrieved from BIOS.

  - If not, install using generic key for Windows 8.1 from Microsoft
    website, then activate later from Windows Settings (Online or By Phone).
- Any other options will not work.

**For Windows 10 :**

- If you upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, all good.
- If you want a clean install, you MUST upgrade to Windows 10 at least one, then clean install using SIMILAR EDITION OEM installation media, it should not ask for any key.

  - Even if it does ask for key, use generic key and activate later from Windows Settings (Online or By Phone).
- If you never have upgraded to Windows 10, there is no way to clean install Windows 10 using Windows 8 key, at least as of now.

**For more details**, for these links :

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/reinstalling-windows-10-after-upgrade/578d0b7f-57e4-4893-b9d1-6cfac0d6290a

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-10-clean-install-window-8-oem-key/21ad0fcc-f759-4d46-9924-84ea9ba47cfd

Answer (score 0):

I just did it without downloading or updating Windows 8. Had to replace hard drive on HP desktop with Windows 8.0. No recovery disks or C0A. Follow instructions per this link:
[Clean install Windows 10 without product key](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-get-windows-10-product-key-start-activation-1514845)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Superuser and thanks for contributing! You should know that generally you want to summarize external sources here, since the links have a bad habit of breaking, and making your answer useless at some point in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think it will upgrade.

Based on [the system requirements for upgrading](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications):

> Latest OS:
>
> Make sure you are running the latest version of either Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.1 Update.

That seems pretty clear cut that you need to upgrade to 8.1. So install 8 -> upgrade to 8.1 -> upgrade to 10

Answer (score -1):

It seems that I need to install Windows 8 then Windows 8.1 then Windows 10 then clean the mess after W8 and W8.1 because the install won't recognize my product key...

Comment: What is the point of doing a clean install if you install Windows 8, it would already be a clean install, besides you can simply choose not to keep anything and that would be a clean install also.  This seems more like a comment then an answer to your question.

Comment: Ramhound clean as in using cmd to delete the Windows.old folder !