# Move my Windows 10 installation (Upgraded) to a new hard drive without formatting the destinantion drive

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade, migration

I got a new laptop. It's a Gateway NE56R41u, that originally came with Win8. I upgraded it to Win8.1 and then to Win 10 (So I don't have Win10 license per se).

Now, before this one I've been using a Toshiba laptop, for which I had bought a 1.5TB hard drive, that I don't want to lose. There's a lot of data on that hard that I can't backup anywhere, bc of the size.

I want to "migrate" the Win10 installation, along with the license and oem data to that 1.5 HDD. No programs or anything, Just the OS, with license and OEM.

Ideally, I'm looking for a way to make Windows install/upgrade media from my current installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your BEST option (if you are worried about the data) is to back it up. See if you can get a 30 day cloud storage trial on OneDrive, Dropbox, Amazon or something. Back up your data, then reinstall windows on the larger drive. Then recover your data.

I have made the mistake of trying new things on "production" devices and losing out. When in doubt, back it up.

If you can spare $10, Google Drive is only $10 per month for 1 TB of storage. Or if you can't spend any money, you could create create like 100 Gmail accounts which each come with 15 GB of free cloud storage! :P

Comment: Can't. I live in a country where I (for various stupid reasons) cannot buy anything (Product or service) unless I can pay for it in cash. So, a transaction to Google (or anyone else is not an option). That's also why I need to keep my license, I have no way to buy a new (legal) WIn10 DVD.

Comment: Keeping your license shouldn't be a problem. You can download a Windows 10 install tool for free from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and if you don't know your license key, you can recover it using a tool like Belarc advisor (https://www.belarc.com/products_belarc_advisor)

As far as the backup goes, you may just need to get creative.

Comment: I know how to get my license key, but it's an oem key, so it won't work with a fresh install, right? Sorry, I don't know much about oem. Also, the OEM folders (the boot logo and whatever else there is) would be lost.

Comment: Boot logo comes from BIOS. The OEM key is tied to the motherboard, so using a fresh image on a new HDD is not an issue. The OEM folders would be lost, but they usually just contain drivers. You should be able to find the drivers on the manufacturers website if Windows doesn't find them automatically

Comment: My `C:\Windows\oem` contains a folder named `Identity Card`, and my `C:\Windows\System32\OEM`  contains a bunch of bat and vbs scripts a subfolder named `Logo` with 2 bmp Gateway logos, which I assumed are the logos I see on boot, and a few other subfolders. So, I ussumed these were important... Not sure if they really are, though

Comment: Your computer will survive without them. But to be safe - back up the folder and copy it back to the new image in the same spot.

Comment: New image? You mean the new drive?

Comment: Yes, sorry, new image meaning the new install of Windows on the new drive.

Comment: OK, apparently Win 10's `Recovery` option (Control Panel -> Large Icons -> Recovery) Writes the entire content of the recovery partition to a Flash drive. I'll start doing this tomorrow (my shift starts now and I need the old laptop), utilizing this recovery USB and I'll write a step-by-step guide of what I did when I'm done. @JoshuaShouds, please post an answer mentioning the license being in the BIOS, so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Here is some evidence of OEM Windows licenses auto-installing onto a newly imaged HDD https://superuser.com/questions/497660/will-a-clean-install-of-windows-8-recognize-an-oem-license-product-key

Comment: Regarding your intentions, use EXTREME caution! My guess is that the recovery steps will WIPE your 1.5 TB drive. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score -2):

Redo Backup can do [Try This](http://redobackup.org/) full Image to another HDD

If the machine(Laptop) comes with pre-Installed windows you dont need to do any

Download the Media Creation Tool for Windows 8.1 from Microsoft and Download the OS came(SL/Home/Pro) with the Laptop and Download the Media Creation Tool for windows 10 and Download the OS Supported to Your Laptop(it means Home/Pro)
You can install windows 8.1 first and then upgrade with Windows 10

Comment: please share the info why i got downvote

Comment: According to the website, it does a full backup/restore of the hard drive. So, as far as I understand, you lose the data on the destination drive. Not what I'm looking for. And, no, I'm not the one, who downvoted.

Comment: About the edited answer: What about the OEM data and the license?

Comment: Pre Installed Means The Key Saved in Your Laptop Bios.  It even wont ask you key if you installing the same OS(SL/Home/Pro).  But you need an empty HDD or Empty Partition for it  [Check] (http://neosmart.net/OemKey/)

Comment: I think I can make an empty partition. Will definitely look into this, although I'd prefer a "safer", i.e. one that doesn't require tampering with the destination drive. But, at worst end I'll give this one a try

Comment: By the way, is there a way to check if the key _is_, actually, in the BIOS? Just in case...?

Comment: Check this https://itsolutionsblog.net/3-ways-to-extract-the-windows-8-product-key/  it will help you

Comment: Your answer is difficult to understand. Please use proper punctuation and improve its grammar.